# Using Laravel + Vue.js, one or two components are not displaying randomly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a project using Laravel + Vue.js.
I made two components -chart and expired data- and they must be showing on the 'Home' page. 
Everything works fine, there is no console error, but randomly one or two components are not showing.

Sometimes if I hit Ctrl + F5, all components are displaying. Then again, if I hit just F5 for a reload, one or two components are not displaying.

Here are my components. It's part of them, the rest are omitted.

**chart.vue**

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("charts here");

    axios.post('/chart')
    .then(response => {
      showChart(response.data)
    });
  },
}
```

**expired.vue**

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      expiredIos: [{}],
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("expired here");
    this.expiredIos = this.getExpiredIosData();
  },
  methods: {
    getExpiredIosData() {
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/expired'
      }).then(
        response => {
          this.expiredIos = response.data
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
    },
  },
}
```

I don't know what is happening here.
Could anyone guess what is this or has anyone experienced this kind of problem?

Comment: Is the component not rendering after you changed something or are you talking about a production environment without code changes between page reloads?

Comment: @Namoshek  No, the components are not displaying even I didn't change anything. I'm running the command ``npm run watch``.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan  No, I just dropped using Vue.js on the project at the moment. Since it's been a long time after trying this, I will try again with Laravel 8 next time.